# How to place a div centered inside a other div (Just a smaller rectangle inside a big one)?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center all the "boxes" inside the boxes. It should be also maintain measures when I'm changing the window size. I'm also trying to distribute the yellow boxes equally inside the purple one.
I tried to different CSS alignments but failed it getting a solid structure.
**I want especially the purple box with yellow boxes centered in the green box.**

Thanks for your tips!

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: red;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
  width: 99%;
  margin-left: 0.25%;
  height: 98vh;

}
.buildground {
  display: grid;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: purple;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;




}

.ground-item{
  border: 1px solid orange;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

}


.buildarea {

  border: 1px solid green;
  margin: 10px;
  justify-content: space-around


}

.two{
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;

}
.three{
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;


}
.four{
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;


}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="buildarea">
      <div class="buildground">
          <div class="ground-item">1</div>
          <div class="ground-item">1</div>
          <div class="ground-item">1</div>
          <div class="ground-item">1</div>
          <div class="ground-item">1</div>
          <div class="ground-item">1</div>
          <div class="ground-item">1</div>
          <div class="ground-item">1</div>
          <div class="ground-item">1</div>
          <div class="ground-item">1</div>
          <div class="ground-item">1</div>
          <div class="ground-item">1</div>
          <div class="ground-item">1</div>
          <div class="ground-item">1</div>
          <div class="ground-item">1</div>
          <div class="ground-item">1</div>
          <div class="ground-item">1</div>
          <div class="ground-item">1</div>
          <div class="ground-item">1</div>
          <div class="ground-item">1</div>
          <div class="ground-item">1</div>
          <div class="ground-item">1</div>
          <div class="ground-item">1</div>
          <div class="ground-item">1</div>
          <div class="ground-item">1</div>
          <div class="ground-item">1</div>
          <div class="ground-item">1</div>
          <div class="ground-item">1</div>
          <div class="ground-item">1</div>
          <div class="ground-item">1</div>

      </div>



    </div>
    <div class="two">Two</div>
    <div class="three">Three</div>
    <div class="four">Four</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: sorry i edit the post. I want especially the purple box with yellow boxes centered in the green box.

Comment: Try [Flex Layout](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), very powerful and very easy to use.

Comment: Is it not to recommend with grid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add flexbox to `designarea` to center horizonatally and `align-self:center` to `.buildground`

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: red;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
  width: 99%;
  margin-left: 0.25%;
  height: 98vh;
}

.buildground {
  display: grid;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: purple;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  align-self: center;
  /* this */
}

.ground-item {
  border: 1px solid orange;
}

.buildarea {
  display: flex;
  /* this */
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin: 10px;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.two {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.three {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.four {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="buildarea">
    <div class="buildground">
      <div class="ground-item">1</div>
      <div class="ground-item">1</div>
      <div class="ground-item">1</div>
      <div class="ground-item">1</div>
      <div class="ground-item">1</div>
      <div class="ground-item">1</div>
      <div class="ground-item">1</div>
      <div class="ground-item">1</div>
      <div class="ground-item">1</div>
      <div class="ground-item">1</div>
      <div class="ground-item">1</div>
      <div class="ground-item">1</div>
      <div class="ground-item">1</div>
      <div class="ground-item">1</div>
      <div class="ground-item">1</div>
      <div class="ground-item">1</div>
      <div class="ground-item">1</div>
      <div class="ground-item">1</div>
      <div class="ground-item">1</div>
      <div class="ground-item">1</div>
      <div class="ground-item">1</div>
      <div class="ground-item">1</div>
      <div class="ground-item">1</div>
      <div class="ground-item">1</div>
      <div class="ground-item">1</div>
      <div class="ground-item">1</div>
      <div class="ground-item">1</div>
      <div class="ground-item">1</div>
      <div class="ground-item">1</div>
      <div class="ground-item">1</div>

    </div>



  </div>
  <div class="two">Two</div>
  <div class="three">Three</div>
  <div class="four">Four</div>
</div>
```